# C++ Standard for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I am trying to install MongoDB driver and is reading this following section
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver

**SCons Options when Compiling the C++ Driver**

Select options as appropriate for your environment. Please note that some flags may not be available on older versions.

**Important note about C++11/C++14:** The boost libraries do not offer a stable ABI across different versions of the C++ standard. As a result, you must ensure that your application, the C++ driver, and boost are all built with the same language standard. In particular, if you are building the C++ driver with C++11 enabled, you must also build your application with C++11 enabled, and link against a C++11 compiled boost. Note that on most systems, the system or package installed boost distribution is not built with C++11, and is therefore incompatible with a C++11 build of the legacy driver.

**Important note about the C++ standard library:** Much like the C++11 issues, it is again critical that all three components (your application, boost, and the C++ driver) be built against the same C++ runtime library. You cannot mix components that have linked against libc++ with those that have linked against libstdc++.

**Important 26compat Note:** If you are using the 26compat branch, the install-mongoclient target is only enabled when the --full flag is provided. Similarly, you must use the --use-system-boost flag when building 26compat.*

My main question, I am trying to find out what standard my visual studio 2015 is running on when I build solution. I have tried to read around but I think I misunderstood the concept of C++11 and C++14. On Microsoft page it mentioned that VS2015 supports C++11,C++14 and C++17. But how do I know what am I using now? I can't find a way to explicitly configure. I am new to C++ and have been coding Java for many years. C++ is confusing to me because there are so many variety such as compilers and standards. Please help me understand and possibly find out what standard I am running.

Comment: I would thank that building your app, the driver and Boost all with VS2k15 would automatically ensure they're compatible.

Comment: Hi but before I can choose which branch to compile, I would need to determine my C++ standard first?

Comment: It really depends exactly what you are compiling. If its mainly the features they already did, great. If it's stuff using lots of `constexpr` in less trivial ways, there's a decent chance that it won't work. If it relies on more tricky template constructions, there's a decent chance that it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses, I just need to get mongodb driver installed for my project. But it seems like i need to determine my C++ standard before picking the right source for driver to compile? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: MSVC is different from the other compilers. They don't let you select the standard, it's only "you get whatever we implemented, take it or leave it". If you want to get an older subset of what MSVC implemented I think you just need to download an older version of MSVC.

Comment: Noodling about standards is not helpful in the context of MSVC++.  Microsoft breaks binary compatibility with every VS release.  Not just because the library implementation may change but primarily because you cannot afford to have multiple copies of the runtime library linked into or loaded by your program.  You simply need to ensure that everything is built by the same VS version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text is mostly nonsense.

ABI's are dictated by compilers, not standards. There is no ABI for C++11, there's one for GCC and a different one for MSVC2015.

"C++11 enabled" is a setting on GCC, and it does affect their ABI. The same applies to libc++ versus libstdc++, neither is part of the C++11 standard. Also, the mixing of build environments and the OS ("system Boost version") is mostly a Linux thing.

MSVC++ isn't GCC, and it doesn't use libstdc++, so all this does not affect you. And Boost versions aren't even a MSVC++ setting anymore, for the last few versions library configuration has been a per-project setting instead. (Tip: Create a Boost.vsprops file for that)